# AJAX Monitor Browser Plugin

Tags: ajax, browser, firefox-addon, google-chrome-extension

I want to write a browser plugin that will allow me to load a web page and will sit and monitor the page for any asynchronous updates, and then write the details of those updates to a file. Please point me to the easiest way to accomplish this or to an existing plugin if one exists. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

[Firebug](http://getfirebug.com/), the *de facto* standard developer tool for Firefox, includes [all of the features you describe](http://getfirebug.com/wiki/index.php/Net_Panel), and though logging requests to a file isn't built-in the [Omnibug](http://www.rosssimpson.com/dev/omnibug.html) extension appears to support that, or you could [build that functionality yourself](http://getfirebug.com/wiki/index.php/Firebug_Internals).

Comment: I have been poking around in firebug for the past 20 minutes and I think I am close. Can you help? I have identified the dom element I want to monitor. All I really care about is when children are added, I want to capture the children. How do I do this?

Comment: You didn't mention monitoring DOM changes in your question. Sorry, I'm not familiar enough with Firebug to answer that.

Comment: OK, I am seeing the info I want in the Net panel. I only can see it when expanding events there. Unfortunately, the NetExport extension to firebug "cannot be installed because it is incompatible". Do you know of a way around that?

Comment: OK, almost there... I have NetExport installed, and it works when I manually export the panel. But, I want to leave this running for days/weeks and I am afraid the Panel will auto-clear itself after it reaches a certain size in memory, and then I will lose the info it has accumulated. Can you think of a workaround?